# Webview not scrolling after adding setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, uiwebview, webview, scroll

i have a webview with the below code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
     webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
webView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

If i comment `webView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);` this then webview will scroll but if i add it then the webview will not scroll any reason why so?

**EDIT**

My Listener

```
OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //do something
        }

        return false;
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `onTouchListener` variable is referencing an implementation that always returns `true`?
From the documentation at
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html
Returns
True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Make sure to return `false`.

Comment: It will be true when you want webView to *not* perform its default action for an specific touch event.